# Two Easy PHP SOAP setHeaders Questions

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Here's the code I'm using to generate the request headers:

```
$headers = array(
                  new SOAPHEADER($this->_ns,'username',$this->_username,false, $this->_actor),
                  new SOAPHEADER($this->_ns,'password',$this->_password,false, $this->_actor));

$this->_client->__setSOAPHeaders($headers);
```

This generates:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <ns2:username SOAP-ENV:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next">test</ns2:username>
  <ns2:password SOAP-ENV:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next">test</ns2:password>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

That's all fine and dandy.

**Here are my two questions:**

The API doc requires that username be *ns1:username* and password be *ns2:password*. Mine are both ns2. First of all, what is the significance of the ns1|2? How can I fix this?

Second question is just is there a way to generate the same result by only calling SOAPHEADER() once?

Comment: WSDL location: http://api.stormpost.datranmedia.com/services/SoapRequestProcessor?wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Not easy to say whether the namespace makes a difference without seeing the declaration & knowing the service, but usually the receiving service looks only for the tags in that particular namespace. As you add `$this->_ns` to both of them, of course they'll be the same. You'll have to provide the proper namespace yourself (prefix doesn't matter, uri does).
2. Why would you want only 1 call?

Comment: I posted the url to the WSDL which should answer #1. For #2, I was just wondering due to my lack of familiarity with the PHP SOAP lib if I was setting the headers as efficiently.

Comment: According to the WSDL, having those namespaces the same shouldn't make a difference, as they are in the same namespace. And for #2, I'd say it's effecient & readable.

Comment: Just for sh*ts and giggles, how would I get the username to be ns1?

Comment: By passing the correct namespace-uri as the first argument to `SoapHeader`. The _uri_ is what matters, not the prefix. So, if you have an example that _requires_ different namespaces for username & password, check out the `xmlns:ns1` & `xmlns:ns2` namespace declarations which should be found somwhere in that example, note their values/uris, and use that uri as their respective first arguments to SoapHeader.